# Show Spark jobs/stages/tasks and their names in GCP Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I moved recently from AWS to GCP and of course they have some similarities and some differences. One of them is that in AWS EMR notebook one could see Spark Jobs/stages/tasks and their progress as the code runs:
[image]

However, in GCP notebook what I see is only number of the stage and its progress:

[image]

Is there a way to show it the way it's shown on AWS, or is it platform-bound?

Comment: Just to be clear I'm using Dataproc in GCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no out-of-the-box solution, you can use monitoring dashboard as described in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/monitoring).
There's also a similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66005309/how-to-display-total-dataproc-job-by-status-in-cloud-monitoring-stackdriver).
If you want a realtime progress bar, you can file a Feature Request on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: So it is platform-bound after all..